# How to get started using Phonegap Build with a Durandal SPA App?

Tags: javascript, cordova, durandal, phonegap-build

I've built a SPA using Durandal and it all works fine in a browser. What I'm trying to do now is wrap it up with Phonegap (ideally using Phonegap Build) and deploy it as an Android app.

The Durandal documentation on the subject (http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Native-Apps-With-PhoneGap-Cordova/) is pretty sparse. It's key points of optimizing the app to generate a main-built.js file were done as were gathering the js/css assets into one place.

However, it doesn't mention anything about Phonegap/Cordova having a `device ready` event rather than a `document ready` one. I've packaged the app according to instructions. It installs alright on my Android device but gets stuck on the splash screen. Other questions have asked about being stuck on the splash screen, but the solutions posted there don't help. I can't help but think something fundamental is missing here?!?

Do I need to have Phonegap specific code in index.html? In any javascript?

Note: I'm using Durandal 1.2 but the same questions apply for v2.0.

Answer (score 7):

You can hook into the Phonegap device ready event in main.js, you can then be sure the device is ready before the shell or any view activate events are fired. This example checks the agent so it will still fire up in a browser. This is from my example Durandal 2 / Phonegap Build project.

https://github.com/BenSinnott/LandmarkTracker

```
define(['durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'durandal/system'], boot);

function boot(app, viewLocator, system) {
    var useragent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (useragent.match(/android/) || useragent.match(/iphone/) || useragent.match(/ipad/) || useragent.match('ios') || useragent.match('Windows Phone') || useragent.match('iemobile')) {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    else {
        onDeviceReady();
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        app.title = 'Landmark Tracker';

        app.configurePlugins({
            router: true
        });

        app.start().then(function () {
            viewLocator.useConvention();
            app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It's just the kind of thing I'm looking for. My adaptation of what you've done still fails but I haven't yet had a chance to properly debug, so will see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

> However, it doesn't mention anything about Phonegap/Cordova having a device ready event rather than a document ready one.

jQuery can listen for document ready via `$(document).ready` but HTML/javascript itself doesn't have a document ready event. The closest pure javascript equivalent is listening for the `DOMContentLoaded` event. Phonegap/Cordova offers the device ready event as documented [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready). Be sure to include `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>` in your `<head></head>` tags.

> It installs alright on my Android device but gets stuck on the splash screen.

Take a look at your config.xml. Do you have `<preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="xxxx"/>` where xxxx is set to some crazy high number?

You could always call `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` after device ready fires but you will need to build in the deviceready listiner. Easy to do using the documentation I provided above. If that doesnt fix it, then we will need to take a look at some of your code to dig into what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try an unminified Version. Means copy all the folders into your assets folder. Then look at logcat. Most likely u had a js error. If that works try the minified version and check if that one throws errors via logcat

Edit: sry this applies of course only for manual build in android not for the online service. For IOS as far as i remember you get the errors thrown in the output window.